# Numeric vector operator overload+ rvalue reference parameter

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, numerical, rvalue-reference

I have the numeric vector template class below (vector for numerical calculations). I am trying make it possible to write `D=A+B+C` where all variables are `Vector` objects. `A`, `B` and `C` should not be modified. My idea is to use `Vector operator+(Vector&& B)` so that after (hopefully) an Rvalue `Vector` has been returned from `B+C`, all subsequent additions are stored in that object i.e. steal the storage of the Rvalue for all subsequent additions. This is in order to eliminate creation of new objects and required storage.

My problem is that I can see from output statements from each function called that `Vector operator+(Vector&& B)` is never called. I cannot understand why since if I have an overloaded dummy function `foo(Vector& B)` and `foo(Vector&& B)` and try `foo(A+B+C)`, then the second function is called exactly as I hoped.

Sorry for the long winded question but this is my first question here and I want to try to be as clear as possible.

Any suggestions as to what I am obviously doing wrong or why I should not be trying this, would be appreciated.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
        int n;
        T* v;
        Vector();
        ~Vector();
        Vector(const Vector& B);
        Vector(Vector&& B);
        inline Vector operator+(const Vector& B) const;
        inline Vector operator+(Vector&& B) const;
};

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& B)
{
        ...
}

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T>&& B)
{
        ...
}

template <typename T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator+(const Vector<T>& B) const
{
        Vector<T> C;
        ...
        return C;
}

template <typename T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator+(Vector<T>&& B) const
{
        ...do stuff to B
        return B;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, got a bit sloppy there.
If I added all the implementations the code be huge so I hoped the snippets above would be enough. The functions go through and add element by element two vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the expression:

```
D=A+B+C
```

`A` and `B` are lvalues, so the call `A+B` calls `Vector::operator(const Vector&)`

That returns an rvalue, let's call it `tmp`, so the next sub-expression is `tmp+C`.

`C` is also an lvalue, so it calls `Vector::operator(const Vector&)` again. That returns another rvalue, lets call it `tmp2`

The final sub-expression is `D=tmp2`, but your type doesn't have a move-assignment operator, so the implicitly-defined copy-assignment operator is used.

i.e. you never invoke `operator+` with an rvalue on the right-hand side, and the only expression which does have an rvalue argument is an assignment which you haven't defined for rvalues.

It would be better to define overloaded *non-member* operators:

```
Vector operator+(const Vector&, const Vector&);
Vector operator+(Vector&&, const Vector&);
Vector operator+(const Vector&, Vector&&);
Vector operator+(Vector&&, Vector&&);
```

This will work for any combination of rvalues and lvalues. (In general `operator+` should usually be a non-member anyway.)

**Edit:** the alternative suggestion below doesn't work, it results in ambiguities in some cases.

Another alternative, if your compiler supports it (I think only clang does,) would be to keep your existing `Vector::operator+(Vector&&)` but replace your `Vector::operator+(const Vector&)` with two overloads distinguished by a ref-qualifier:

```
Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& v) const&
{
  Vector tmp(*this);
  tmp += v;
  return tmp;
}

Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& v)&&
{
  *this += v;
  return std::move(*this);
}
```

This reuses `*this` when it's known to be an rvalue, i.e. it uses move semantics when the left-hand side of the addition is an rvalue, compared to your original code which can only use move semantics when the right-hand side is an rvalue.  (N.B. the code above assumes you've defined a member `operator+=` as suggested in David Rodriguez's answer)

Comment: Ahhh... 
So a `Vector operator+(Vector&& A, const Vector& B)` would give me the desired behaviour?

Comment: yes, because that allows you to use move semantics when the left-hand side of the addition is an rvalue

Comment: @larsc: You don't need (nor want) the rvalue-reference on the first argument of the free function version. You should take the first argument *by value*, and let the compiler deal with it. The problem with the *rvalue-reference* in the signature, is that (and because it is a template) it will also bind to an *lvalue* and then you will probably do the wrong thing internally (unless, of course, you provide two overloads).

Comment: I disagree that the rvalue-reference is not wanted, my solution shows four overloads that will handle any combination of lvalues and rvalues  and use avoid copies when possible. A single function taking an argument by value can't do that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I meant that you don't want *only* that overload, as it will be used for both *rvalue* and *lvalues* (I believe would have to double check, but type deduction in templates is a bit trickier...) also in the member function options, the one taking a reference should take a *const* reference and suffers from the same problem that my solution has: it will not be optimal in the case of `a + (b+c)` (*rvalue* as second argument)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, ah gotcha. I meant the two members to be in addition to the existing one taking an rvalue reference, I'll edit to clarify that, and add the const, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you provide `operator+=` as a member method and then reuse that from a free function `operator+` defined as:

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T> operator+( Vector<T> lhs,              // by value
                     Vector<T> const & rhs ) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Given a call `a + b + c`, which groups as `(a+b) + c`, the compiler will create a copy of `a` for the first call to `operator+`, modify that in place (`lhs += rhs`) and then *move it* into the returned value. It will then *move* that returned value (unless it elides the move) into the argument of the second `operator+`, where it will be modified in place again, and then *moved* to the return value.

Overall, a single new object will be created, holding the result of `a+b+c`, providing semantics equivalent to:

```
Vector<T> tmp = a;
tmp += b;
tmp += c;
```

But with the nicer, more compact syntax `a + b + c`.

---

Note that this will not handle `a + (b+c)` graciously, and will create *two* objects, if you want to support that, you will need to produce multiple overloads.

Comment: Your final sentence alludes to it, but doesn't make it entirely clear that your single non-member `operator+` is sub-optimal for all `lvalue + rvalue` cases, such as your `a + (b+c)` and also any `lvalue + func_returning_rvalue()`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I was actually thinking what is the minimum subset of overloads that need to be provided for an optimal solution... I will think about that tonight.

Comment: There are four cases: l+l, r+l, l+r, r+r, and only the first should need to allocate memory. I think you can reduce it to three functions if you use member functions with ref-qualifiers: `V::operator+(const V&) const&` deals with the l+l case and allocates, `V::operator+(const V&)&&` handles r+l and reuses `*this`, and `V::operator+(V rv)` handles `l+r` and `r+r` and reuses `rv`. I'll need to test that with clang to see if it's ambiguous though.

Comment: Bah, both r+l and r+r are ambiguous, so I think you need all four overloads, which can (and should) be non-members